# Marketplace checkout system

Tags: ruby, interview-questions, rspec

I was given the following code challenge as part of an interview process, unfortunately I did not get through to the next stage. Any advice on how I could improve would be very much appreciated.

Here is the spec:

> Our client is an online marketplace, here is a sample of some of the products available on our site:
>
> `Product code  | Name                   | Price`
>
> `001           | Lavender heart         | £9.25`
>
> `002           | Personalised cufflinks | £45.00`
>
> `003           | Kids T-shirt           | £19.95`
>
> If you spend over £60, then you get
>   10% off of your purchase. If you buy 2 or more lavender hearts then
>   the price drops to £8.50. Our check-out can scan items in any order,
>   and because our promotions will change, it needs to be flexible
>   regarding our promotional rules.
>
> The interface to our checkout looks like this (shown in Ruby):
>
> `co = Checkout.new(promotional_rules)`
>
> `co.scan(item) co.scan(item) price = co.total`
>
> Implement a checkout system that fulfills these requirements. Do this
>   outside of any frameworks. We’re looking for candidates to demonstrate
>   their knowledge of TDD.
>
> Test data
>
> Basket: 001,002,003
>
> Total price expected: £66.78
>
> Basket: 001,003,001
>
> Total price expected: £36.95
>
> Basket: 001,002,001,003
>
> Total price expected: £73.76

Here is my code:

**Product:**

```
#/lib/product.rb    

class Product
  class << self
    attr_reader :price
  end
end
```

**Kids T-Shirt:**

```
#/lib/products/kids_t_shirt.rb

require './lib/product'

class KidsTShirt < Product
  @price = 19.95
end
```

**Lavender Heart:**

```
#/lib/products/lavender_heart.rb

require './lib/product'

class LavenderHeart < Product
  @price = 9.25
end
```

**Personalised Cufflinks:**

```
#/lib/products/personalised_cufflinks.rb

require './lib/product'

class PersonalisedCufflinks < Product
  @price = 45
end
```

**Checkout**

```
#/lib/checkout.rb

class Checkout
  def initialize(promotional_rules)
    @items = {}
    @promotional_rules = promotional_rules
  end

  def scan(item)
    quantity = @items[item.class]
    @items[item.class] = quantity ? quantity + 1 : 1
  end

  def total
    @promotional_rules.total(@items).round(2)
  end
end
```

**Promotional Rules**

```
#/lib/promotional_rules.rb

require './lib/products/kids_t_shirt'
require './lib/products/lavender_heart'
require './lib/products/personalised_cufflinks'

class PromotionalRules
  def total(items)
    current_total = 0

    items.each do |item, quantity|
      current_total += item_pricing(item, quantity)
    end

    total_pricing(current_total)
  end

  private

  def item_pricing(item, quantity)
    if item.eql?(LavenderHeart)
      lavender_heart_pricing(item, quantity)
    else
      general_item_pricing(item, quantity)
    end
  end

  def total_pricing(total)
    total > 60 ? total * 0.9 : total
  end

  def lavender_heart_pricing(item, quantity)
    quantity >= 2 ? 8.5 * quantity : item.price * quantity
  end

  def general_item_pricing(item, quantity)
    item.price * quantity
  end
end
```

**Checkout Spec**

```
#/spec/checkout_spec.rb

require 'rspec'
require './lib/products/kids_t_shirt'
require './lib/products/lavender_heart'
require './lib/products/personalised_cufflinks'
require './lib/checkout'
require './lib/promotional_rules'

describe 'Checkout' do
  describe '#total' do
    context 'when lavender hearts/over £60 promotional rules are present' do
      before do
        @lavender_heart = LavenderHeart.new
        @personalised_cufflinks = PersonalisedCufflinks.new
        @kids_t_shirt = KidsTShirt.new
        @promotional_rules = PromotionalRules.new
      end

      it 'provides the total cost of the items checked out' do
        co = Checkout.new(@promotional_rules)
        co.scan(@lavender_heart)
        co.scan(@personalised_cufflinks)
        co.scan(@kids_t_shirt)

        expect(co.total).to eq(66.78)
      end

      it 'activates a discount when two or more lavender hearts are bought' do
        co = Checkout.new(@promotional_rules)
        co.scan(@lavender_heart)
        co.scan(@kids_t_shirt)
        co.scan(@lavender_heart)

        expect(co.total).to eq(36.95)
      end

      it 'activates a discount when over £60 is spent' do
        co = Checkout.new(@promotional_rules)
        co.scan(@lavender_heart)
        co.scan(@personalised_cufflinks)
        co.scan(@lavender_heart)
        co.scan(@kids_t_shirt)

        expect(co.total).to eq(73.76)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For TDD, I'd expect a lot more tests.

Comment: Agreed, I only tested the test cases they gave, which was foolish, do you have any other advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Product

Your `Product` class and it's descendants are coded in a really weird way. What would be wrong with:

```
class Product
  attr_reader :price

  def initialize(price)
    @price = price
  end
end
```

You don't really need a class for every product - those classes don't do *anything*. All they differ in is an *instance* variable, so a product could very well be an *instance* of a class.

If having separate class for each product would prove beneficial in any way, you should still set price in `initialize`. Absolutely no need for any singleton class shenanigans.

#### Checkout

Ruby's Hashes allow you to specify default value. No need for `scan` to be that unreadable.

```
class Checkout
  def initialize(promotional_rules)
    @items = Hash.new(0)
    @promotional_rules = promotional_rules
  end

  def scan(item)
    @items[item.class] += 1
  end

  def total
    @promotional_rules.total(@items).round(2)
  end
end
```

#### PromotionalRules

They specifically asked you to make the system *flexible regarding promotional rules*. You didn't - anyone who would wan't to add a new promotion, would need to edit `PromotionalRules` class. What your potential employee would expect here, is a system to easily define new promotions. Example interface:

```
class MarchPromotions < PromotionalRules
  discount_for(kids_t_shirt) do |quantity|
    quantity >= 2 ? 0.85 : 1.0
  end
end
```

I won't go into the details here, as it could very well look much different. The main point is, *someone should be able to define new promotion rules **without** hacking your code*, but by specifying them outside of it - be it in another `.rb` file like in my example, or by listing rules in YAML or XML - that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have another code test to do that this will help with!